# Integrating $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos x(1+\cos x)^3}{3}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Is there any "easy" way of integrating $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos x(1+\cos x)^3}{3}dx?$$ I only can find the hard way.

Thanks a lot

Comment: I would simply solve it by expanding the bracket.

Comment: You could try integrating by parts with $u'=\cos x$ and $v=(1+\cos x)^3/3$.

Comment: @Keen-ameteur I'm getting 0 with that, but it seemed nice. The problem is I have sin(x) as a product and when doing the definite it gets me 0.

Comment: Well if the indefinite integral $F$ satisfies that $F(0)=F(2\pi)$, then it should be $0$. I haven't computed it myself though out of lazyness.

Answer (score 1):

I've done it using that the sine and cosine over a $[0,2\pi]$ interval are $0.0.$ The result is $\frac{5\pi}{4}$.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you consider the "hard way".

$$ \frac{1}{3}\int_0^{2\pi}{\cos{x}(1 + \cos{x})^3 dx} $$
$$ \frac{1}{3}\int_0^{2\pi}{\cos^4{x} + 3\cos^3{x} + 3\cos^2{x} + \cos{x} dx} $$

We can use 
$$ \cos^2(x) = \frac{1 + \cos{(2x)}}{2}.$$

Because $\cos(x)$ is symmetric over the interval we can remove any odd exponents. Also notice that the above just reduces to $\frac{1}{2}$. So we have ...

$$ \frac{1}{3}\int_0^{2\pi}{\cos^4{x} + 3\cos^2(x) dx} $$
$$ \frac{1}{3}\int_0^{2\pi}{\cos^4{x} dx} + \int_0^{2\pi}{\cos^2(x) dx}$$
$$ \frac{1}{12}\int_0^{2\pi}{(1 + \cos{(2x)})^2dx} + \int_0^{2\pi}{\frac{1}{2} dx}$$
$$ \frac{1}{12}\int_0^{2\pi}{1 + 2\cos{(2x)} + \cos^2{(2x)}dx} + \int_0^{2\pi}{\frac{1}{2}dx}$$
$$ \frac{1}{12}\int_0^{2\pi}{dx} + \frac{1}{24}\int_0^{2\pi}{dx} + \int_0^{2\pi}{\frac{1}{2}dx}$$
$$\frac{1}{24}\int_0^{2\pi}{15 dx} = \frac{5\pi}{4}$$

Answer (score 0):

A variant on @student's approach is to use$$\begin{align}\int_0^{2\pi}(\cos^4x-\cos^2x)dx&=-\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^2x\sin^2xdx\\&=-\frac14\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^22xdx\\&=-\frac142\pi\frac12\\&=-\frac{\pi}{4},\\\int_0^{2\pi}(\cos^4x+3\cos^2x)dx&=-\frac{\pi}{4}+4\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^2xdx\\&=-\frac{\pi}{4}+4\frac122\pi=\frac{15\pi}{4},\end{align}$$so the original integral is $\frac54\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

A general method for integrating trigonometric functions is by using the *Weierstrass substitution* $t:=\tan(x/2)$. Under this substitution, $\sin x=2t/(1+t^2)$ and $\cos x=(1-t^2)/(1+t^2)$. Then $\cos x+1=2/(1+t^2)$, so our integral becomes $$\frac13\int_{\mathbb R}\frac{1-t^2}{(1+t^2)^4}dt=\frac13\int_\mathbb{R}\frac{2}{(t^2+1)^4}-\frac{1}{(t^2+1)^3}dt.$$
I'm sure you can do the rest, e.g. by means of a trigonometric substitution $t\mapsto\tan\theta$.